# How to display a website's header information with PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

How can I get the Header Informations like this web page (below) with using php

This web site [Check website HTTP Server Header Information](http://webtools.live2support.com/header.php)

**Result:**

```
HTTP Status for: "http://www.abc.com"
The title is: ""

Keywords: ""
Description: ""

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2013 12:00:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/4.4.4-8+etch6
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.4-8+etch6
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 4):

Use PHPs function `get_headers`:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

If you also want the *meta keywords* and *meta description* use [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php):

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP function `get_header();`.
This function will return an array with all the header fields.

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
print_r(get_headers($url));
```